# Dev-C++ 536870912 float variable output

Tags: c, compiler-errors, dev-c++

I just made this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define PI 3.1416

int main (){
    float x;

    x = PI;

    printf("x equals: %i.\n",x);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

and the 'Pi' number is 536870912. Can anybody tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the `%i` format specifier for `printf`. This is for signed integers. Instead use `%f` as `x` is a `float`.